# Symbols used as Hash keys get converted to Strings when serialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

When I assign an Array or Hash to an attribute of a Mongo document, it gets properly 
serialized except for Symbols when they are used as Hash keys. Simple example:

```
irb>MyMongoModel.create :some_attr => {:a => [:b,:c]} 
=> #<MyMongoModel _id: 4d861c34c865a1f06a000001, some_attr: {:a=>[:b, :c]}> 

irb>MyMongoModel.last 
=> #<MyMongoModel _id: 4d861c34c865a1f06a000001, some_attr: {"a"=>[:b, :c]}>
```

Please, note that `some_attr` is retrieved as `{"a"=>[:b, :c]}`, not as 
`{:a=>[:b, :c]}`

This also happens for nested Hashes (e.g., inside of Arrays or other Hashes). Is there a way to preserve Symbols in such cases?

**Solution**

I'm using YAML to manually serialize `some_attr` - YAML.dump (or `Object#to_yaml`) before storing, and YAML::load after reading the attribute. YAML preserves the serialized object better. ActiveRecord is using YAML to implement its `serialize` class method on `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Comment: what rails and ruby versions? My Rails 3.0.5 and Ruby EE works fine

Comment: Thanks for the YAML tip. I'm using a key/value collection with a symbol key and an arbitrary object as the value. Serializing with YAML is perfect for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More than likely this has to do with the ORM you are using to provide the persistance layer for the model. You can probably wrap `some_attr` with a method that returns it in the form of a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` which you can then access with either strings or arrays. Since you are using Rails, this functionality can be activated by calling the `with_indifferent_access` method on the Hash object. (If you have an array of Hash objects, you'll need to call it on each one of course) The method will return the same hash, but then symbol lookups will work.

From your code:

```
new_hash = MyMongoModel.last.some_attr.with_indifferent_access
new_hash[:a] # Will return the same as new_hash['a']
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the structure of the serialized object is not know in advance, hashes can be nested at any level. But, as it appears, there's no better way, so, I'm accepting this answer. Thanks!

Comment: You can write a simple method to inspect and loop through the structure, converting the hashes as needed.

Answer (score 3):

the culprit here is the BSON serialization. when you serialize a symbol used as a key for hashes, it is actually translated to a string and when you ask it back you get the string instead of the symbol.

i'm having the same problem as you and i'm thinking of extending the Hash class to include a method to convert all the "string" keys to :symbols.

unfortunately i'm not on Rails so i cannot use the `with_indifferent_access` as suggested by ctcherry.

Comment: This is actually a "feature" of JSON (for which BSON is simply a binary encoding).  All keys must be strings. see http://www.json.org/

Comment: of course, i was not referring to it like a bug, just an explanation of why it happens...

Comment: The problem with converting string keys to symbols is that the structure of the serialized object is not know in advance, so, hashes can be nested at any level. What I've decided to do instead, is using manual serialization of `some_attr`, using YAML.dump (before writing), and YAML::load (after reading). YAML preserves the object just as it is. Rails is using it for implementing its "serialize" class method in ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about preserving symbols but you can convert the strings back to symbols.

```
str.to_sym
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this, works well and you have define the field as Hash:

https://github.com/mindscratch/mongoid-indifferent-access